# AJAX Load and PHP Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have created a simple form which submits data to the database.

I want to use Ajax so that when submit is pressed, a loading bar shows and then takes you to the success! page after a few seconds. How do i go about this?

Also the following code gives me the following error, what do i need to fix - **SOLVED**:

```
Notice: Undefined index: command in F:\xamppnew\htdocs\web\billing.php on line 5
```

Code:

```
    <?php
include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
session_start(); 

if ($_REQUEST['command']=='update'){
        $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
        $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
        $address=$_REQUEST['address'];
        $phone=$_REQUEST['phone'];
        $item_id = $_SESSION['item_id'];
        $quantityorder = $each_item['quantity'] = $_SESSION['quantity1'];
        $cartTotal = $_SESSION['cartTotal'];

    // Add this product into the database now
    $sql = mysqli_query($link,"insert into transactions values('','$item_id','$quantityorder','$cartTotal','$name','$address','$email','$phone')");

        die('Thank You! your order has been placed!');
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<title>Billing Info</title>
<script language="javascript">
function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}
</script>
<script language="javascript">
    function validate(){
        var f=document.form1;
        if(f.name.value=='' || f.email.value=='' || f.address.value=='' || f.phone.value=='' ){
            alert('You have not filled in all fields');
            f.name.focus();
            return false;
        }
        f.command.value='update';
        f.submit();
    }
</script>
</head>



<body>
<div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
  <?php include_once("template_header.php");?>
  <div id="pageContent">
    <div style="margin:24px; text-align:left;">

    <br />
<form name="form1" onsubmit="return validate()">
    <input type="hidden" name="command" />
    <div align="center">
        <h1 align="center">Billing Info</h1>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="2px">
             <tr><td>Product ID:</td><td><?php echo $item_id = $_SESSION['item_id'];?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Total Quantity:</td><td><?php echo $each_item['quantity'] = $_SESSION['quantity1']; ?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Order Total:</td><td>£<?php echo $cartTotal = $_SESSION['cartTotal'];?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Your Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="name" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Address:</td><td><input type="text" name="address" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="email" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Phone:</td><td><input type="text" name="phone" onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)' /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="submit" value="Place Order" /></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>


      <?php include_once("template_footer.php");?>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!--================================== code for "stack_ajax.php" start here ==================================-->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/external_css.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_src/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function validate(){

    var f=document.form1;
    if(f.name.value=='' || f.email.value=='' || f.address.value=='' || f.phone.value=='' ){
        alert('You have not filled in all fields');
        f.name.focus();
        return false;
    }

     f.command.value='update';

     postData = $("#form1").serializeArray( );

     $.ajax({
       type       : "POST",
       data       : postData,
       dataType   : "html",
       url        : "ajax_response.php",
       async      : true,
       beforeSend : function( ) {
                      $("#ajax_image_div").show();
                    },
       success    : function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                     ajax_response_status = parseInt(data, 10);

                     if(ajax_response_status)
                      window.location.href='success_message.php';
                       else
                        window.location.href='failed_message.php';
                    },
       error      : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     alert(textStatus);
                    },
       complete   : function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                     $("#ajax_image_div").hide();
                    }
      });

     return true;
  }

  function isNumberKey(evt){
   var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
   if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
       return false;

   return true;
  }
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />



</head>

<title>Billing Info</title>

<body>

<div id='ajax_image_div' style="display:none;">
  <img id="ajax_loader_image" style="vertical-align:middle" src='image/ajax_loader.gif'>
</div>
<div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
  <div id="pageContent">
    <div style="margin:24px; text-align:left;">
      <br/>
      <div align="center">
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="hidden" name="command" /> 
          <h1 align="center">Billing Info</h1>
          <table border="0" cellpadding="2px">
             <tr><td>Your Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="name" id="user_name" /></td></tr>
             <tr><td>Address:</td><td><input type="text" name="address" /></td></tr>
             <tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="email" /></td></tr>
             <tr><td>Phone:</td><td><input type="text" name="phone" onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)' /></td></tr>
             <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="button" name="submit" value="Place Order" onClick="return validate()"/></td></tr>
          </table>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
<!--================================== code for "stack_ajax.php" end here ==================================-->



<!--============================== code for "ajax_response.php" start here ==============================-->
 <?php
  /*
   Note : I made changes in your HTML form ( You can add session variable by yourself )  and delete following lines
     1. <?php include_once("template_header.php");?>
     2. <?php include_once("template_footer.php");?>
  */

  sleep(3); /* Wait for 3 seconds before executing below code, by doing so
               you will be able to see "AJAX LOADER" on the page.
            */

/* print_r($_POST); // You will get all the FORM input data in this array. */

  $name          = $_REQUEST['name'];
  $email         = $_REQUEST['email'];
  $address       = $_REQUEST['address'];
  $phone         = $_REQUEST['phone'];
  $item_id       = $_SESSION['item_id'];
  $quantityorder = $each_item['quantity'] = $_SESSION['quantity1'];
  $cartTotal     = $_SESSION['cartTotal'];

   // Add this product into the database now
   $sql = mysqli_query(
                       $link,
                             "insert 
                              into
                                 transactions

                              values
                                 ('','$item_id','$quantityorder','$cartTotal','$name','$address','$email','$phone')"
                      );
    if( $sql )
     echo 1; /* When SQL query will execute successfully. */
       else
        echo 0; /* When SQL query will not execute successfully. */
    exit;
?>
<!--============================== code for "ajax_response.php" end here ==============================-->



/* ================================== code for "external_css.css" start here ==================================*/
#ajax_image_div {
top:30%;
left:30%;
width:50%;
height:50%;
position:absolute;
z-index:999;
}

#mainWrapper {
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
}

#ajax_loader_image {
 position:relative;
 top:35%;
left:35%;
}

/* ================================== code for "external_css.css" end here ==================================*/



<!-- ============================= code for "success_message.php" start here ============================= -->
<?php
 echo 'Thank You! your order has been placed!';
?>
<!-- ============================= code for "success_message.php" end here ============================= -->



<!-- ============================= code for "failed_message.php" start here ============================= -->
<?php
 echo 'An error occurred, please try after some time ';
?>
<!-- ============================= code for "failed_message.php" end here ============================= -->


<!--
Note : make sure your directory structure must be same as below

php_ajax ( create a folder with "php_ajax" and put all the code inside it )
 1. css [ create a folder with "css" name ]
    A. external_css.css
 2. image [create a folder with "image" name]
    A. ajax_loader.gif [ You may download it using internet :-) ]
 3. jquery_src [ [create a folder with "jquery_src" name]]
    A. jquery-1.11.0.min.js [ jQuery framework, you may download it using internet ]
 4. ajax_response.php
 5. failed_message.php
 6. stack_ajax.php
 7. success_message.php

 Let me know if you have any problem after implementing this. I put all the codes in separate files to
 make DEBUG task very easy.
-->
```

Comment: Thanks a lot parvesh this is a great help, haha might get confused trying to implememnt this but will do it now!

Comment: i am glad that i could help you :-)

Comment: is there some way i could contact you for more quick help?